# How to Install node.js to broadcast from my home

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, http, https

I am studying Node.js presently and wonder if it is possible to broadcast my sites from one of my home PCs.

For local publishing I am playing with this code:

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

fs.readFile('index.html', (err, html) => {
    if(err){
        throw err;
    };

    const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-type','text/html');
        res.write(html);
        res.end();
    });

    server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
        console.log('Server started on port: '+port);
    });
});
```

But I am not sure what needs to be done to make my sites available to the public.  How do I set up the "hostname" and whatever else needs to be done to broadcast one or more sites.

I am not asking for a complete robust server code, just a minimal site that says Hello on the WEB.

Many thanks

Comment: when you say "hostname", do you mean DNS name or IP Address? Are you asking how to print helloworld on a page using Node.js?

Comment: Gab  I already know how to publish locally.  The code above is able to send the index.html to a browser.  Works great.  But how do I ppush it to be on the WEB?

Comment: Technically, it is on the web. If you gave someone your IP Address, they would be able to get to your page. To have a domain name pointing to your page, you need to buy one and then have it point to your IP Address

Comment: I own at least 8 domains by a host who does not support Node.JS.  How is the pointing the IP done?  That I do not know...

Comment: Do I need to have a static IP on my account?

Comment: I've got to be honest, I'm lost now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy Route:
See Arun's answer.

Formal route:

1. Buy a domain name (sounds like you have some)
2. Contact your ISP to get it pointed to a public IP,
3. Get a server to have the public IP
4. Point that server to your local machine's ip:port.
5. If you have node running and listening on that port it should work.

Informal Route:
(Skips to step 3 above)

3. Go to your router's configuration page and find the public IP.
4. While at the configuration page set up port forwarding. (This directs traffic to the public ip to your local machine's port that you're listening on.)
5. should be able to access that page via the public IP. (assuming firewalls are set to open those ports too).

Anyone feel free to correct me/add detail to the steps.

Comment: This is the best answer so far.  Thanks T-Rez

Comment: That is a good answer @T-Rez, since Dekoss is new to nodejs I felt it would be easier for him to set it up with an already existing platform.

Answer (score 2):

you can host it in platforms like Heroku, firebase etc. they give you a url which is publicly accessible.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#introduction

Comment: OP is asking about how to host a website from his personal PC

Comment: Yes, I know some hosts who cater to Node.js, but I was wondering how I could do it from home.

Comment: Arun, I looked ar Heroku. Seems interesting. I downloaded it and will mess with it a bit.   Thanks..